# Padding on List Items Extends Past List

Tags: html, css

If you put `<p>` inside of a `<section>` element and give the `<p>` padding, the `<section>` element expands to hold the entire paragraph element AND its padding. Fantastic.

If you put padding on a `<li>` which is contained by a `<ul>`, the `<ul>` element **does not expand** to fit the `<li>`'s with the padding. Instead it allows the padding to stretch past the "box". What the heck is going on?

Please try out the page below to see what I mean. The padding for the `<li>` is exaggerated at 30px to clearly make an example.

```css
body {
  font-size: small;
  font-family: Verdana;
  background-color: #D9D9D9;
  margin: 0px;
}
header {
  background-color: #878CA1;
  margin: 10px;
}
nav {
  background-color: #878CA1;
  margin: 10px;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
nav ul li {
  padding: 30px;
  display: inline;
  background-color: #D9D9D9;
}
header h2#slogan {
  float: right;
}
section#main {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
#main p {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="images/dummy-logo.png" alt="Vape Central Logo">
  <h2 id="slogan">Vapor Products and Accessories</h2>
</header>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="tanks.html">Best Tanks</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="batteries.html">Best Batteries</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section id="main">
  <p>Test</p>
</section>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `display` of the children `li` elements from `inline` to `inline-block` if you want the parent element's dimensions to respect the padding.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/p5jw0wps/)

```
nav ul li {
    padding: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #D9D9D9;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. I was beginning to think my whole concept of the CSS "box-model" was wrong.